# How do I run a script file in Windows?

Tags: docker, powershell, pyodide

I am trying to build Pyodide from source on Windows. In their documentation they recommend using Docker. From the [documentation](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/development/building-from-sources.html):

> ```
> 1 Install Docker
>
> 2 From a git checkout of Pyodide, run ./run_docker or ./run_docker --pre-built
>
> 3 Run make to build.
> ```

I don't understand how to run [./run_docker](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/blob/main/run_docker)?
I don't even know exactly what the file is. Is it a shell script?

Comment: `run_docker` is a `bash` script, so you'll need an environment that can run Bash scripts on Windows, such as WSL, but I don't know if and how that can be combined with the use of Docker.

Comment: That is a bash shell script. That will only run on linux (unless you count WSL, which shouldn't be required to run docker). Perhaps you need to run that inside of a debian docker image? I would raise an issue on their GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

Combining your question, "How do I run a script file in Windows?", with the information provided (you want to run a file called run_docker from the Pyodide project) you should get started by installing the [Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2 (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). After you install WSL, you will need to open a command prompt, run `bash` to enter the Ubuntu linux distribution. From here you should follow the steps for building on Linux. When you run into a problem you can search the internet for solutions related to "Linux" or "Ubuntu".